# dataGridView, MySQL data and changing information on the fly

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010

I am filling dataGridView with data selected from MySQL table with this code

```
MySqlConnection sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(sqlParams);

try
{
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConnection);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns["ColumnName"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
}
catch {
}
```

And one of the columns contains sum data (for example 10.34 USD), but problem is what in my country format it must be "10,34" (coma instead of dot), so i want to change this sign while filling dataGridView to proper one.
Is it possible? Or is there another methods? Because now i am storing sums in "dot" format because so i can use MySQL commands like SUM.

In short: in MySQL i have 10.34, but user must see 10,34 :)

Comment: A `decimal` has no _format_ and `ToString` takes the current culture into account. So i assume that you're using the wrong datatype(likely `string)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. The formatting is settable in the datagridview.

```
dataGridView1.Columns["ColumnName"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "C";
```

"C" means for Currency formatting. "N" is for general number formatting. Also for your country specific formatting you can use the class CultureInfo where you can set the specific format provider for the current thread.